# Delay time on onmouseover

Tags: html, css

I am having some issue with changing the onmouse function. The images change as desired but they are too quick. Is there a way to slow them down?

Please help :)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: that link also seems to be dead/not functioning properly, all I see is `Not Acceptable!`. is this a joke?

Comment: sorry! i thought i had added the code <img src="images/arrow-down-icon.png"  onmouseover="this.src='images/arrow-down-icon-mint.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/arrow-down-icon.png'" />

Answer (score 1):

I think the `transition-delay` may help. here's an example.

```
div{
  transition: 0s background-color;
}

div:hover{
  background-color:red;    
  transition-delay:1s;
}
```

but you may want to include a bit more information, I have no idea what your looking for here, and the link doesn't work.